# PGFPlots colored regression legend

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

how can i have this legend?

[image]

in this plot:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}        % Grafici
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest,%
            width=12cm,%
            height=9cm%
            }


%*********************************************************************************
% Impostazioni Pgfplots
%*********************************************************************************

\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
0.05 0.17
0.05 0.041
0.05 0.023
0.1 0.332
0.1 0.089
0.1 0.041
0.15 0.5
0.15 0.132
0.15 0.06
}\tableA

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression]
{regression}
{\tableA}

\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\xdef\intercept{\pgfplotstableregressionb}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[/pgf/number format/fixed,
legend pos=outer north east,
grid=major,
xmin=0, xmax=0.2,
ymin=0, ymax=0.6,
point meta min={0},
point meta max={0.2},
yticklabel shift=2pt,
xticklabel shift=2pt,
legend pos=north west,
legend cell align=left,
minor tick num=4,
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
minor xtick={%
0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,%
0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,%
0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,%
0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19},%
extra x ticks={0,0.05,...,0.3},
extra x tick style={
    xticklabel pos=right,
    xticklabel style={text depth=0pt}
},
extra y ticks={0,0.1,...,0.7},
extra y tick style={
    yticklabel pos=right
},
tick style={thin,black},
xlabel=\large $m$,
ylabel=\large $\Delta l$,
colorbar horizontal,
colorbar style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    xticklabel shift=2pt,
    xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}
},
axis line style={draw=none}, after end axis/.append code={\draw (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);},
colormap={new}{color(0cm)=(violet);color(1cm)=(blue);color(2cm)=(cyan);color(3cm)=(green);color(4cm)=(yellow);color(5cm)=(orange);color(6cm)=(red)}
]
\addplot [point meta=explicit,
    scatter,
    mark=*,
    draw=none]
    table[meta=X] {\tableA};

\addplot [mesh,point meta=x,domain=0.025:0.175,very thick,samples=10] {\slope*x+\intercept};
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE at Jake's answer:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5mm,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}        % Grafici

\pgfplotsset{%
            mesh line legend/.style={legend image code/.code=\meshlinelegend#1},%
            /pgf/number format/use comma,%
            compat=newest,%
%            height=9cm,%
            width=12cm%
}



%*********************************************************************************
% Impostazioni Pgfplots
%*********************************************************************************

\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
0.05 0.17
0.05 0.041
0.05 0.023
0.1 0.332
0.1 0.089
0.1 0.041
0.15 0.5
0.15 0.132
0.15 0.06
}\tableA

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression]
{regression}
{\tableA}

\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\xdef\intercept{\pgfplotstableregressionb}



%% Code for the coloured line legend
\makeatletter
\long\def\meshlinelegend#1{%
    \scope[%
        #1,
        /pgfplots/mesh/rows=1,
        /pgfplots/mesh/cols=4,
        /pgfplots/mesh/num points=,
        /tikz/x={(0.44237cm,0cm)}, 
        /tikz/y={(0cm,0.23932cm)},
        /tikz/z={(0.0cm,0cm)},
        scale=0.4,
    ]
    \let\pgfplots@metamax=\pgfutil@empty
    \pgfplots@curplot@threedimtrue

    \pgfplotsplothandlermesh
    \pgfplotstreamstart

    \def\simplecoordinate(##1,##2,##3){%
        \pgfmathparse{1000*(##3)}%
        \pgfmathfloatparsenumber\pgfmathresult
        \let\pgfplots@current@point@meta=\pgfmathresult
        \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfqpointxyz@orig{##1}{##2}{##3}}%
    }%

    \simplecoordinate(0,0,0)
    \simplecoordinate(0.25,0,0.125)
    \simplecoordinate(0.5,0,0.25)
    \simplecoordinate(0.75,0,0.375)
    \simplecoordinate(1,0,0.5)
    \simplecoordinate(1.25,0,0.625)
    \simplecoordinate(1.5,0,0.75)
    \simplecoordinate(1.75,0,0.875)
    \simplecoordinate(2,0,1)

    \pgfplotstreamend
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \endscope
}%
\makeatother
%% End code for the coloured line legend



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
/pgf/number format/fixed,
legend pos=outer north east,
grid=major,
xmin=0, xmax=0.2,
ymin=0, ymax=0.6,
point meta min={0},
point meta max={0.2},
yticklabel shift=2pt,
xticklabel shift=2pt,
legend pos=north west,
legend cell align=left,
minor tick num=4,
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
minor xtick={%
0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,%
0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,%
0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,%
0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19},%
extra x ticks={0,0.05,...,0.3},
extra x tick style={
    xticklabel pos=right,
    xticklabel style={text depth=0pt}
},
extra y ticks={0,0.1,...,0.7},
extra y tick style={
    yticklabel pos=right
},
tick style={thin,black},
xlabel=\large $m$,
ylabel=\large $\Delta l$,
colorbar horizontal,
colorbar style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    xticklabel shift=2pt,
    xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}
},
axis line style={draw=none}, after end axis/.append code={\draw (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);},
colormap={new}{color(0cm)=(violet);color(1cm)=(blue);color(2cm)=(cyan);color(3cm)=(green);color(4cm)=(yellow);color(5cm)=(orange);color(6cm)=(red)}
]
\addplot [%
    point meta=explicit,
    forget plot,
    scatter,
    scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color},
    mark=*,
    draw=none]table[meta=X] {\tableA};

\addplot [mesh,mesh line legend,point meta=x,domain=0.02:0.18,thick,samples=10] {\slope*x+\intercept};%
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

UPDATE this is an update to the percusse's answer

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.5mm,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}        % Grafici

\pgfplotsset{%
            colormap legend/.style={legend image code/.code={\path[draw=none,shading=tempshading,shade] (0cm,0mm) rectangle (0.5cm,0.8pt);}},
            /pgf/number format/use comma,%
            compat=newest,%
%            height=9cm,%
            width=12cm%
}


%*********************************************************************************
% Impostazioni Pgfplots
%*********************************************************************************

\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
0.05 0.17
0.05 0.041
0.05 0.023
0.1 0.332
0.1 0.089
0.1 0.041
0.15 0.5
0.15 0.132
0.15 0.06
}\tableA

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression]
{regression}
{\tableA}

\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\xdef\intercept{\pgfplotstableregressionb}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
/pgf/number format/fixed,
legend pos=outer north east,
grid=major,
xmin=0, xmax=0.2,
ymin=0, ymax=0.6,
point meta min={0},
point meta max={0.2},
yticklabel shift=2pt,
xticklabel shift=2pt,
legend pos=north west,
legend cell align=left,
minor tick num=4,
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
minor xtick={%
0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,%
0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,%
0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,%
0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19},%
extra x ticks={0,0.05,...,0.3},
extra x tick style={
    xticklabel pos=right,
    xticklabel style={text depth=0pt}
},
extra y ticks={0,0.1,...,0.7},
extra y tick style={
    yticklabel pos=right
},
tick style={thin,black},
xlabel=\large $m$,
ylabel=\large $\Delta l$,
colorbar horizontal,
colorbar style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    xticklabel shift=2pt,
    xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}
},
axis line style={draw=none}, after end axis/.append code={\draw (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);},
colormap={new}{color(0cm)=(violet);color(1cm)=(blue);color(2cm)=(cyan);color(3cm)=(green);color(4cm)=(yellow);color(5cm)=(orange);color(6cm)=(red)}
]
\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec{new}{2cm}\result
\def\tempb{\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{tempshading}{3cm}}%
\expandafter\tempb\expandafter{\result}%
\addplot [mesh,point meta=x,domain=0.02:0.18,thick,samples=1000,colormap legend] {\slope*x+\intercept};
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\addplot [%
    point meta=explicit,
    scatter,
    scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color},
    mark=*,
    draw=none]table[meta=X] {\tableA};

\addplot [mesh,point meta=x,domain=0.02:0.18,thick,samples=1000] {\slope*x+\intercept};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: now i am undecided ! lol

Comment: The solution in my answer automatically uses the line thickness and the colormap used in the plot.

Comment: You have to add `forget plot` to the options of the first plot command (the one you don't want a legend entry for), or reverse the order of your `\addplot` commands.

Comment: how can i set the samples for the line legend ? to make it equal to the line of regression?

Comment: i use only 10 for speed up the compilation during the modifying. When i compile definitely the document, I increase the samples to get a more beautiful plot..

Comment: I've edited my answer, the legend now uses the same number of samples as the plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\addlegendentry` creates legend entries starting from the first plot in the axis, it doesn't matter where you call the command. Since you only want a legend entry for the second plot, you'll have to remove the first one from the list. You do that by adding `forget plot` to the options of the first plot.

You will then get a coloured legend entry, but unfortunately, it shows a small mesh, not a line. Usually, you could just add `line legend` to the plot options to make the legend image a line, but that doesn't work with lines of varying colours like yours. You'll have to adjust the `legend image code`.

Here's a style `mesh line legend` that uses an adapted version of the code used for drawing the normal mesh legend. The legend image will be drawn with the same options as the plot (thickness, color map, number of samples). If you call

```
\addplot [mesh, mesh line legend, ...] ...;
```

you'll get

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.5mm,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}        % Grafici

\pgfplotsset{%
            mesh line legend/.style={legend image code/.code=\meshlinelegend#1},%
            /pgf/number format/use comma,%
            compat=newest,%
%            height=9cm,%
            width=12cm%
}



%*********************************************************************************
% Impostazioni Pgfplots
%*********************************************************************************

\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
0.05 0.17
0.05 0.041
0.05 0.023
0.1 0.332
0.1 0.089
0.1 0.041
0.15 0.5
0.15 0.132
0.15 0.06
}\tableA

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression]
{regression}
{\tableA}

\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\xdef\intercept{\pgfplotstableregressionb}



%% Code for the coloured line legend
\makeatletter
\long\def\meshlinelegend#1{%
    \scope[%
        #1,
        /pgfplots/mesh/rows=1,
        /pgfplots/mesh/cols=4,
        /pgfplots/mesh/num points=,
        /tikz/x={(0.44237cm,0cm)}, 
        /tikz/y={(0cm,0.23932cm)},
        /tikz/z={(0.0cm,0cm)},
        scale=0.4,
    ]
    \let\pgfplots@metamax=\pgfutil@empty
    \pgfplots@curplot@threedimtrue

    \pgfplotsplothandlermesh
    \pgfplotstreamstart

    \def\simplecoordinate(##1,##2,##3){%
        \pgfmathparse{1000*(##3)}%
        \pgfmathfloatparsenumber\pgfmathresult
        \let\pgfplots@current@point@meta=\pgfmathresult
        \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfqpointxyz@orig{##1}{##2}{##3}}%
    }%

    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {0,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/samples}}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\x/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/samples}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\x/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/samples}*3}
        \simplecoordinate(\x,0,\y)
    }

    \pgfplotstreamend
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \endscope
}%
\makeatother
%% End code for the coloured line legend



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
/pgf/number format/fixed,
legend pos=outer north east,
grid=major,
xmin=0, xmax=0.2,
ymin=0, ymax=0.6,
point meta min={0},
point meta max={0.2},
yticklabel shift=2pt,
xticklabel shift=2pt,
legend pos=north west,
legend cell align=left,
minor tick num=4,
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
minor xtick={%
0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,%
0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,%
0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,%
0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19},%
extra x ticks={0,0.05,...,0.3},
extra x tick style={
    xticklabel pos=right,
    xticklabel style={text depth=0pt}
},
extra y ticks={0,0.1,...,0.7},
extra y tick style={
    yticklabel pos=right
},
tick style={thin,black},
xlabel=\large $m$,
ylabel=\large $\Delta l$,
colorbar horizontal,
colorbar style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    xticklabel shift=2pt,
    xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}
},
axis line style={draw=none}, after end axis/.append code={\draw (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);},
colormap={new}{color(0cm)=(violet);color(1cm)=(blue);color(2cm)=(cyan);color(3cm)=(green);color(4cm)=(yellow);color(5cm)=(orange);color(6cm)=(red)}
]
\addplot [%
    point meta=explicit,
    scatter,
    scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color},
    mark=*,
    draw=none, forget plot]table[meta=X] {\tableA};

\addplot [mesh,mesh line legend,very thick,point meta=x,domain=0.02:0.18,samples=10] {\slope*x+\intercept};%
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are awesome guys ! :O

Comment: now is perfect !

Answer (score 6):

You can use the convenient `\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec` command to convert your colormap to a shading and then define a legend image code with it. I've defined a simple `colormap legend` style to draw a colorbar in the legend.

Note that `\addlegendentry` respects the sequence of `\addplot` commands so I switched the order of the plotting commands to get the line as a first legend entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{colormap legend/.style={
legend image code/.code={%
\path[draw=none,shading=tempshading,shade] (0cm,-0.4mm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.8mm);
        }
    }
}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest,%
            width=12cm,%
            height=9cm%
            }

\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
0.05 0.17
0.05 0.041
0.05 0.023
0.1 0.332
0.1 0.089
0.1 0.041
0.15 0.5
0.15 0.132
0.15 0.06
}\tableA

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression]
{regression}
{\tableA}

\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\xdef\intercept{\pgfplotstableregressionb}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[/pgf/number format/fixed,
legend pos=outer north east,
grid=major,
xmin=0, xmax=0.2,
ymin=0, ymax=0.6,
point meta min={0},
point meta max={0.2},
yticklabel shift=2pt,
xticklabel shift=2pt,
legend pos=north west,
legend cell align=left,
minor tick num=4,
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
minor xtick={%
0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,%
0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,%
0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,%
0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19},%
extra x ticks={0,0.05,...,0.3},
extra x tick style={
    xticklabel pos=right,
    xticklabel style={text depth=0pt}
},
extra y ticks={0,0.1,...,0.7},
extra y tick style={
    yticklabel pos=right
},
tick style={thin,black},
xlabel=\large $m$,
ylabel=\large $\Delta l$,
colorbar horizontal,
colorbar style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    xticklabel shift=2pt,
    xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}
},
axis line style={draw=none}, after end axis/.append code={\draw (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);},
colormap={new}{color(0cm)=(violet);color(1cm)=(blue);color(2cm)=(cyan);color(3cm)=(green);color(4cm)=(yellow);color(5cm)=(orange);color(6cm)=(red)}
]
\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec{new}{2cm}\result
\def\tempb{\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{tempshading}{3cm}}%
\expandafter\tempb\expandafter{\result}%
\addplot [mesh,point meta=x,domain=0.025:0.175,very thick,samples=10,colormap legend] {\slope*x+\intercept};
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\addplot [point meta=explicit,
    scatter,
    mark=*,
    draw=none,empty legend]
    table[meta=X] {\tableA};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how i can make the rectangle with the same thickness as the line of regression? what is the thickness of the command "very thick" ?

Comment: If you look at the definition of `colormap legend/.style`, you can see that the dimensions are `6mm x 1.2 mm`. If you search the file `tikz.code.tex` you can find the definitions of predefined line widths. Starting from `ultra thin` to `ultra thick` the widths are `0.1,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.2,1.6` all in `pt`. The regular normal line has `1pt`.

Comment: (0cm,-0.4mm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.8mm); i see only this..

Comment: @FormlessCloud  Yes the first coordinate is the lower left corner and the second one is the upper right. So you can try using `(0mm,-1pt) rectangle (6mm,0.6pt)`. If the resulting line is too low shift the `x` coordinates up until you are happy with it.

Comment: check my update answer

Comment: the default length of the rectangle is 0.5 cm as I have put it? and how can i do to center the rectangle on the number at right of it?