# Legendary entry

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

How can i change the picture of the legendary? I would like to have to lines insted...

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal image,
        %unit vector ratio={1 1},
        scale=0.6,
        %width=4.5cm,
    %height=3cm,
        xlabel={$\theta$},
        xtick={-1,-0.5,0.5,1},
        xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel={$O(\theta^3)$},
        ylabel style={anchor=south},
        ytick={-0.5,0.5},
        xmin=-1.25, xmax=1.25,
        ymin=-0.7, ymax=0.7,
        samples=500,
        every tick/.style={black,line width=0.5pt},
        legend style={
            anchor=outer north east,
            nodes={scale=0.9,inner sep=1pt, transform shape}
        },
 ]
\addplot[mesh,
        colormap={}{
            color=(white)
                        color=(blue)
            color=(white)
        },
                point meta=x,
                thick,
                %forget plot,
                domain=-1.1:1.1] {cos(deg(x))-1};
\addlegendentry{\(\sin(\theta)-\theta\)}
\addplot[mesh,
        colormap={}{
            color=(white)
                        color=(red)
            color=(white)
        },
                point meta=x,
                thick,
                %forget plot,
                domain=-1.1:1.1] {sin(deg(x))-x};
\addlegendentry{\(\cos(\theta)-1\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility is to simply use [this legendary answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59075/121799).

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
            mesh line legend/.style={legend image code/.code=\meshlinelegend#1},%
}
\makeatletter
\long\def\meshlinelegend#1{%
    \scope[%
        #1,
        /pgfplots/mesh/rows=1,
        /pgfplots/mesh/cols=4,
        /pgfplots/mesh/num points=,
        /tikz/x={(0.44237cm,0cm)}, 
        /tikz/y={(0cm,0.23932cm)},
        /tikz/z={(0.0cm,0cm)},
        scale=0.4,
    ]
    \let\pgfplots@metamax=\pgfutil@empty
    \pgfplots@curplot@threedimtrue

    \pgfplotsplothandlermesh
    \pgfplotstreamstart

    \def\simplecoordinate(##1,##2,##3){%
        \pgfmathparse{1000*(##3)}%
        \pgfmathfloatparsenumber\pgfmathresult
        \let\pgfplots@current@point@meta=\pgfmathresult
        \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfqpointxyz@orig{##1}{##2}{##3}}%
    }%

    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {0,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/samples}}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\x/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/samples}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\x/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/samples}*3}
        \simplecoordinate(\x,0,\y)
    }

    \pgfplotstreamend
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \endscope
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal image,
        %unit vector ratio={1 1},
        scale=0.6,
        %width=4.5cm,
    %height=3cm,
        xlabel={$\theta$},
        xtick={-1,-0.5,0.5,1},
        xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel={$O(\theta^3)$},
        ylabel style={anchor=south},
        ytick={-0.5,0.5},
        xmin=-1.25, xmax=1.25,
        ymin=-0.7, ymax=0.7,
        samples=500,
        every tick/.style={black,line width=0.5pt},
        legend style={mesh line legend,
            anchor=south east,
            xshift=20pt,
            nodes={scale=0.9,inner sep=1pt, transform shape}
        },
 ]
\addplot[mesh,mesh line legend,
        colormap={}{
            color=(white)
                        color=(blue)
            color=(white)
        },
                point meta=x,
                thick,
                %forget plot,
                domain=-1.1:1.1] {cos(deg(x))-1};
\addlegendentry{\(\sin(\theta)-\theta\)}
\addplot[mesh,mesh line legend,
        colormap={}{
            color=(white)
                        color=(red)
            color=(white)
        },
                point meta=x,
                thick,
                %forget plot,
                domain=-1.1:1.1] {sin(deg(x))-x};
\addlegendentry{\(\cos(\theta)-1\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just asking for my own personal interest... I suppose that the legend symbol comes from the fact that the plots has `mesh` option!? What if two dummy invisible line plots were added, just to create the legend?

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, you could do that. A slight downside is that you need to give the dummy plots the same color. If you do that, `\addlegendimage` will be an even more straightforward choice. There you can add whatever you like. The point here is that you could adjust `\pgfmathparse{\factor*(##3 - \rangea)}` to create a legend image in which the color changes. This is how https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59075/121799 works.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I completely switched gears and now just use Jake's great answer.

Comment: Nice answer although I do not understand the low level code.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I guess what happened in Jake's answer is that Jake looked up the definition of `\pgfplotsplothandlermesh@defaultlegend@img` in `pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex` and adjusted it to his needs. There you can find a bunch of `\simplecoordinate` statements, which define the surface symbol of the ordinary `mesh legend`. The perhaps most important thing there is the statement `\let\pgfplots@current@point@meta=\pgfmathresult`, which sets the meta (i.e. color) of a point. This gets linked to the third entry of the coordinates, and is how the fading effect is achieved.